# Remote Debugging Java - Solr

Tags: java, debugging, solr, jvm

I have Solr 5.1 and JDK 1.8 installed on my system right now. I want to debug the Solr server but when I try this command:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9000 -jar start.jar
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: JDWP Non-server transport dt_socket server=y suspend=y address=9000 must have a connection address specified through the 'address=' option
ERROR: JDWP invalid option: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket server=y suspend=y address=9000
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try `java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n -jar start.jar`

Comment: i got this error, ERROR: JDWP option syntax error: -agentlib:jdwp=server=y transport=dt_socket address=4000 suspend=n

Comment: btw, if your host has a public IP you should bind to localhost. debug ports allow remote code execution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It shoould be something like this

`java "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9000" -jar start.jar`

It's working now

Comment: FYI this is outdated. You know longer run Solr via `java -jar start.jar`. See Fabrizio's answer for the current solution

Answer (score 2):

From the solr home dir you can execute

> bin/solr start -f -a
>   "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9000"